# Restore Hyper-V image to bare metal

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, restore, v2p

We run Hyper-V on our Win2008R2 server with a DC and Terminal Server as virtualised machines.

We're finding that our current usage necessitates a new server to give our terminal server more breathing room.

Is it possible to restore a HyperV image onto the bare metal? Ideally, the HyperV host machine would become the DC, and a new server would be for Terminal Services.

Comment: if the TS server is windows 2008 r2 you can just native boot the vhd file with no loss of performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might try using Windows Server Backup, since it does support bare metal restores to different hardware.

http://www.wbadmin.info/articles/hardware-independent-bare-metal-restore-windows-server-2008.html

Comment: Great recommendation! I didn't know WSB had actually been updated to, well, work. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, [SCVMM2008R2 does NOT support V2P](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd221390.aspx), it only supports P2V and V2V. Currently, the only way to accomplish this task is by using a third party tool.

I personally am a fan of [Acronis](http://www.acronis.com/backup-recovery/advanced-server-virtual/) but there are plenty of third-party tools to help handle  this for you. If you only have to do this once, I would recommend using a trial version of these softwares (so you don't have to purchase the license unless you really need to.)

Comment: Acronis licenses aren't very expensive and if you have it you will probably end up with other uses.

Comment: I agree. You'll end up using the software a lot more than for just this usage case.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, to go V2P, you need to use a third party tool.

Whatever tool you use, Acronis or (what I have been using) Backup Exec System Recovery ( http://www.symantec.com/products/purchasing.jsp?pcid=pcat_business_cont&pvid=1602_1&om_sem_cid=biz_sem_nam_us_Google_SMB_Store_SR_SE&mktsrc=paidsearch&om_sem_kw=symantec+backup+exec+system+recovery+server ), you must use the licensed version, not the demo version to get the "restore anywhere" (aka restore to different hardware) functionality.

In the past (Win2003 era and earlier), there were issues related to restoring a DC to a different system, as the NIC MAC was involved somehow in the DC logic. I am hopeful this is resolved in Win2008, but have no direct experience in this area.

Comment: You are correct in that. I apologize for any misinformation. The Acronis trial does NOT enable you to restore, only to back up.

Answer (score 0):

An easier (and better solution) would be to add a new server to your existing hyper-v cluster to add additional resources to your server. I'm also curious as to what usage drives you to an additional server (the resource usage of a DC is usually unnoticeable) One of the benefits of virtualization is that hardware platform change or adding additional resources should be transparent to the guest OS.  If you really must devirtualize (and agin I'd really think hard about that), I would suggest using Windows server backup after installing the drivers for the destination hardware.  Restore the DC first then the terminal server.

Answer (score -1):

You should look at getting [SCVMM 2008r2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/system-center/virtual-machine-manager.aspx). With that you can can do a virtual to physical conversion. I've never done it so I cant say how difficult or successful you'll be, but if it works well, as I'm guessing it will, you'll be done in probably half the time.

Edit: Apparently I'm full of crap today, just ignore this and move on to something that works. ;)

Comment: That's not true, buddy. Sorry.